# Can I create connected apps programmatically?

Tags: rest-api, connected-apps

Is there a way to define connected apps w/o opening the UI? Has anyone already created apps like that? Any advice would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:** As of version 32 you can now supply your own ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret when creating a Connected App.

You can use the [Salesforce Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/) to create a Connected App, it provides the [ConnectedApp](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_connectedapp.htm) metadata type for this purpose. You can either use the [File Based method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_file_based_calls_intro.htm) or the [CRUD method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_crud_based_calls_intro.htm) (preferable for programatic creation).

> Represents a Connected App application. A connected app is an application that integrates with salesforce.com using APIs. Connected apps use standard SAML and OAuth protocols to authenticate, provide Single Sign-On, and provide tokens for use with Salesforce APIs. In addition to standard OAuth capabilities, connected apps allow administrators to set various security policies and have explicit control over who may use the applications. It extends the Metadata metadata type and inherits its fullName field.
>
> ConnectedApp components have the suffix .connectedapp and are stored in the connectedapps folder.

This API is available in any language supporting HTTP callouts using **Web Services** (Salesforce provides a **WSDL** to consume in your client app). If your using a Java, there is a prebuilt client library available [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector). There is also an [Apex wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) around the API if your interested in doing this natively.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew. Is there any sample code that tells how I can use Metadata Types?? The code sample in that page uses soap Api. So I'm wondering if I can follow the same procedure. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, what language are you using and i can advise accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Right now I'm using Groovy / Java. My short term goal is to create a connected app (as automated as possible) in each and every new pod once it is added.

Comment: I'm able to create apps now with code. There was a small mistake in my code so I kept getting errors the whole day. Now its working. Thank you once again.

Comment: Awesome so please you got it working, i love the Metadata API! :-)

Comment: Yes. It's really good. If you don't mind I've one more question. Could you please tell me, how I can access SamlSsoConfig Object with Metadata API? Thanks.

Comment: Also can you tell me the way I can get consumer secret from a created app. I know it's a protected value but I need to get the value to finish this job.

Comment: As of version 32 you can now supply your own ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret when creating a Connected App.